# Custom function to find date column in df and standardize name to "date" in R

Tags: r, date

A lot of my work involves unioning new datasets to old, but often the standardized "date" name I have in the master dataset won't match up to the date name in the new raw data (which may be "Date", "Day", "Time.Period", etc...). To make life easier, I'd like to create a custom function that will:

1. Detect the date columns in the new and old datasets
2. Standardize the column name to "date" (oftentimes the raw new data will come in with the date column named "Date" or "Day" or "Time Period", etc..)

Here are a couple datasets to play with:

```
Dates_A <- seq(from = as.Date("2017-01-01"), to = as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "day")
Dates_B <- seq(from = as.Date("2017-01-01"), to = as.Date("2017-12-31"), by = "day")
Numbers <- rnorm(365)

df_a <- data.frame(Dates_A, Numbers)
df_b <- data.frame(Dates_B, Numbers)
```

My first inclination is to try a for-loop that searches for the class of the columns by index and automatically renames any with Class = Date to "date", but ideally I'd also like the function to solve for the examples below, where the class of the date column may be character or factor.

```
Dates_C <- as.character(Dates_B)
df_c <- data.frame(Dates_C, Numbers)
df_d <- data.frame(Dates_C, Numbers, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

If you have any ideas or can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, we could check whether a particular column is `Date` class, get a logical index and assign the `name` of that column to 'date'

```
is.date <- function(x) inherits(x, 'Date')
names(df_a)[sapply(df_a, is.date)] <- 'date'
```

Assuming that there is only a single 'date' column in the dataset.  If there are multiple 'date' columns, inorder to avoid duplicate column names, use `make.unique`

```
names(df_a) <- make.unique(names(df_a))
```

Answer (score 1):

akrun's solution works for columns of class `Date` but not for columns of classes `factor` or `character` like you ask at the end of the question, so maybe the following can be of use to you.

```
library(lubridate)

checkDates <- function(x) {
    op <- options(warn = -1)  # needed to keep stderr clean
    on.exit(options(op))      # reset to original value
    !all(is.na(ymd(x)))
}

names(df_c)[sapply(df_c, checkDates)] <- 'date'
names(df_d)[sapply(df_d, checkDates)] <- 'date'
```

Note that maybe you can get some inspiration on both solutions and combine them into one function. If `inherits` returns `TRUE` all done else try `ymd`.